# How WP does Mortgage affordability calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of how this site: https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/mortgage/affordability-calculator/results
I need to understand the logic behind its calculation so i can build this in JS and incorporate into Wordpress.
I've been able to figure out how it allocates the downpayment but not the purchase price of the house.Can someone please help me understand how it calculates the estimated property value?.

Answer (score 0):

They've created an algorithm to determine what amount the user can afford based on the user's previous answers. You need that algorithm/equation.

WordPress has nothing to do with how the price is determined...

This is not a question for this forum. It's a question that you should ask a realtor or a mortgage professional, I'm not sure it's information that's going to be easy to find though, as it's part of the reason why people pay realtors and mortgage professionals to do what they do.

Comment: WordPress especially has nothing to do with it as it's not even WordPress...